# Get element from list of list based on index from another list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I would like to retrieve specific elements within a list of lists without using list comprehension, loops, or any iterative approach in Python.

For example, given this list:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[3,4],[5,6,7]]
```

and this vector:

```
[0,0,1]
```

I would like to retrieve the 0th element on the 0th list, the 0th element of the 1st list, and the 1st element of the 2nd list:

```
[1,2,3,4][0] -> 1
[3,4][0] -> 3
[5,6,7][1] -> 6
```

Which should give this result:

```
[1,3,6]
```

Is this possible in python?

Comment: did you try a simple for loop? what you can do as list comprehensions can be done with a simple loop.

Comment: I edited the question. For performance sake - I don't want to use loops as well.

Comment: @RoeeAnuar if it is just about performance, why you are not using *list comprehension* ? They are pretty performance efficient

Comment: There is no way to "magically" get the things you want without iterating your lists. You need to at least access each element of both lists once. Without measuring I would tend to use a list comp on zipped inputs lists to get to the wanted result. Unless your usecase varies widely you can go for lists, for huge inputs you can use a generator that generates the result. For the full result you still need to touch each element once albeit you do not need to keep all of it in memory at the same time.

Comment: Since I'm dealing with a huge list I would like to use a direct pointer to the element I'm looking for. I remember there was something similar in R using double brackets.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternate:

```
x = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4],[5,6,7]]
y = [0,0,1]
res = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    res.append(x[i][y[i]])
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `zip`

```py
l = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4],[5,6,7]]
i = [0,0,1]
op = []

for index, element in zip(i, l):
    op.append(element[index])
```

output

```
[1, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a *list comprehension* with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is one of the most *Pythonic* way to achieve this:

```
>>> my_list = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4],[5,6,7]]
>>> my_vector = [0,0,1]

>>> [x[i] for x, i in zip(my_list, my_vector)]
[1, 3, 6]
```

However, since OP can not use *list comprehension*, here's an alternative using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with [*lambda expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) as:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x, y: x[y], my_list, my_vector))
[1, 3, 6]
```

*In the above solution, I am explicitly type-casting the object returned by `map()` to `list` as they return the iterator. If you are fine with using *iterator*, there's no need to type-cast.*

Answer (score 1):

using `map` you can do this way

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4],[5,6,7]]
b = [0, 0, 1]
result = list(map(lambda x,y: x[y], a,b))
print(result)
```

output

```
[1, 3, 6]
```